# Joomla how to add dynamic route seo friendly URL

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

I am creating a blog module in which I want to load a post by url slug.
How can I convert the url

```
index.php?option=com_directory&view=directory&id=2
```

to

```
index.php/hello-world
```

Any suggestion, please.

Comment: This question has also been asked at: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/18379/120

Comment: Sorry, i deleted that question

Comment: It's fine to ask on more than one Stack Exchange website (especially when one is still in beta) but useful to cross reference to reduce the duplication of effort in answering the question.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the official Joomla Documentation "Writing a router" [here](https://docs.joomla.org/Supporting_SEF_URLs_in_your_component#Writing_a_router).